# E-mail field not required on checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout, email

I have a Magento 1.9.1 installation and I wish to convert the e-mail field to be non-required on the checkout process.

Comment: Since Magento needs a unique identifier when registering the customer attribute option for E-mail is required, without the possibility of disabling its requirement.   You can edit the attribute directly via the MySQL tables, However you'll need to create a new customer attribute that is required for a unique username.  Ultimately what is the reason for needing to do such?

Comment: Please read this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185544/make-email-address-not-required-in-magento